# long vs. short branches in version control

Tags: version-control, branch

I wonder whether anyone knows some research done with the question "What is good/bad in long/short branches in version control?"

I'm specifically interested in academic research performed in this field. My questions are:

- What problems (or conflicts) long branches may produce and how to deal with them
- How to split a big task onto smaller branches/sub-tasks
- How to coordinate the changes in multiple short branches, related to the same code

Thanks in advance for links and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following article explaining the [branch-per-task](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/branch-per-task-workflow-explained.html) branching pattern. Hope it helps.